# Postgres procedure won't recognize parameter when executed

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters, procedure

I have the following procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test_proc(
IN _intid integer DEFAULT 0)
LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
DO $$
DECLARE dteStart date;

BEGIN
    SELECT Startmonth FROM table1 WHERE id=_intid  INTO dteStart;
    RAISE NOTICE 'dteStart: %', dteStart;
END;
$$;
$BODY$;
```

When calling the above procedure using:

```
CALL test_proc(1)
```

I get the error:

> column _intid  does not exist.

When using positional parameter I get the error:

> there is no parameter $1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use a  `DO` statement in a `LANGUAGE sql` function, instead of using `LANGUAGE plpgsql` straight away? I'm pretty sure that is the source of the scoping problem.

Comment: The argument to `DO` is a string constant, and there is no variable substitution in a string constant. Write a PL/pgSQL function.

Comment: Thanks. Deleting DO and replacing sql by plpgsql did the job.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer was provided via a comment. (& Why isn't this a closure category, it is all too frequent?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in [comment 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76229467/postgres-procedure-wont-recognize-parameter-when-executed#comment134428548_76229467) [and comment 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76229467/postgres-procedure-wont-recognize-parameter-when-executed#comment134429272_76229467) use `LANGUAGE plpgsql`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test_proc(
IN _intid integer DEFAULT 0)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
...
```